# Remove "Edit" button from more section of UITabBar

Tags: xcode

I saw the answer here: [How to disable the edit button that appears in the more section of a UITabBarController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825066/) but I cant figure out where to put the code.

Right now I have a universal app, with multiple view controllers, where does the code go? Also the solutions said "Become a delegate of moreViewController", how do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Add a line of code in life cycle method i.e. app did finish launching with options:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application
{ 
    tabBarController.customizableViewControllers=nil;

}
```

Comment: do you know how to stylize that more screen like the table and stuff?

Comment: @ShawnaMacNabb Yes,you can,I have pasted a sample code snippet [here](http://pastebin.com/RXNE9sWF) ,hope it helps,thanks :)