# Disable Edit Button in ios tab bar

Tags: ios, ios7, uitabbarcontroller

I know that it was a old question but i can't solve it. I made a Tabbar controller with seven tab item in storyboard with tab bar controller not in custom tab bar so, i want to hide an edit button on more section of tab bar.

for that i code as:

```
 on application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method

_tabbarconroller.customizableViewControllers=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:nil];
```

and also add a method

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated
{

    UINavigationBar *morenavbar = navigationController.navigationBar;
    UINavigationItem *morenavitem = morenavbar.topItem;

    morenavitem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
}
```

but it is not working in iOS7 please give me answer or any resource for this,

Comment: Have you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/825066/how-to-disable-the-edit-button-that-appears-in-the-more-section-of-a-uitabbarcon

Comment: i check it but it is not working @PradhyumanSinh Chavda

Comment: i think it is custom tab bar controller not on storyboard controller

Answer (score 1):

Use `UITabBarController's customizableViewControllers` `property` to make it `nil` :

```
yourTabBarController.customizableViewControllers = nil;
```

Comment: i write a code in my AppDelegate.m file on did finish launching mehod
like as:-
_tabbarconroller.customizableViewControllers=nil;
and in AppDelegate.h i declare tab bar as
@property(strong,nonatomic)UITabBarController *tabbarconroller;
but it is not working.