# How to hide Edit button on navigation bar after click on more button on tabbar (In swift)?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift2

As I have 7 Tabbar button, iOS creates "more" button automatically and after click on that remaining tabbar button appears with "Edit" button on navigation bar.
I don't want this button, is there any way to remove or hide it?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/a/1499585/2774832?

Comment: Yes,  didn't understand 
where to add that code? in AppDelegate or UITabBarController class? In both place no luck