# Removing the rightBarButtonItem from moreNavigationController of UITabBarController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have added `tabBar` in my app and remove the `rightBarButtonItem` with the code:

```
UITableView *moreTableView = (UITableView *)tabController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view;
    tabController.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;
```

Now, when I navigate to other screen and click `More` button of `tabBar`, `rightBarButtonItem` appears again. If I uses back navigation button it doesn't appear and works fine. However, when I tap `More` button from tabBar it appears again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I used

```
tabController.customizableViewControllers = nil;
```

and it worked fine :)

Comment: This works better than `moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil;` because it does not accidentally remove the rightBarButtonItem from a VC on the More tab when More is touched while one of those VCs is visible.  Do this whenever the tabBar VCs are set.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work for me, cant figure out why yet. Edit: Looks like it has to be set **after** you set the `viewControllers` property.

Answer (score 2):

You should call `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil` in each viewControllers `viewDidLoad` where you want to get rid of it.

Otherwhise could you show more code of your implementation?

Comment: I don't want to hide back button. I want to hide edit button from moreNavigationController.