# How to remove the "edit" button top right corner of "More" in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, swift3, uitabbarcontroller

I've been trying to remove the "edit" button than appears on top right corner of in "more" section of UITabBarController, by adding TabBarController class to it and do the following inside:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.moreNavigationController.delegate = self
    self.customizableViewControllers = nil
    self.moreNavigationController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.isEnabled = false
    self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = nil
}
}
```

But this doesn't work. The edit button still appears.

How can I remove this edit button?

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825066/how-to-disable-the-edit-button-that-appears-in-the-more-section-of-a-uitabbarcon?rq=1

Comment: can you add screenshot ?

Comment: @Surjeet thanx man, I didnt see that post.

Comment: @beckas Welcome bro..

Answer (score 3):

Set a class for your main UITabBarController. Then in viewdidload, specify that none of your controllers are customizable.

```
class MainTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.customizableViewControllers = []
    }

}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [answer in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/825066/how-to-disable-the-edit-button-that-appears-in-the-more-section-of-a-uitabbarcon?rq=1) helped me solve it as suggested by @Surjeet.

For Swift 3 people here is the function that needs to be added in order to remove the button:

```
func navigationController(_ navigationController: UINavigationController, willShow viewController: UIViewController, animated: Bool) {
    let morenavbar = navigationController.navigationBar
    if let morenavitem = morenavbar.topItem {
        morenavitem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
    }
}
```